# Multiple result select inside a main select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a n-to-1 relation in MySQL tables.

Houses can have many owners.

I would like to list all owners for a house.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT id, name, address
   ,(
      SELECT CONCAT(firstname)
      FROM owners
      WHERE houses_id = houses.id
    ) AS 'owner_firstname' 
FROM houses;
```

but i get this results

```
Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I would like to have result like this

```
100 | Liberty House | 200, NY Street | me, myself, Iren
```

Answer (score 4):

To address your error: you had a sub-query for your select that brought back multiple owners.  The query needed to bring back one literal, in your case, the list of names.  You can achieve this in MySQL using the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to combine the names of owners for a particular house:

```
SELECT h.id, h.name, h.address, GROUP_CONCAT(o.firstname) AS owner_firstname
FROM houses AS h
INNER JOIN owners AS o ON h.id = o.houses_id
GROUP BY h.id, h.name, h.address
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select id, name, address, 
      (select group_concat(firstname separator ', ') 
             from owners where houses_id = houses.id) as 'owner_firstname' 
from houses;
```